# Client authentication for certificate issued by AWS Apigateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to do client authentication for AWS ApiGateway .I am not able to find CA certificate for AWS ApiGateway . where I should download this CA certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client certificate **is** the authority.  It's self-signed.  You use this certificate on your server exactly the same way you'd use a CA file -- it authenticates itself.

Comment: I don't understand why it is not specified anywhere in AWS website. Thank you man